# Magento 2.3 Saleable stock qty does not equal Global Attribute Qty

Tags: magento2, simple-product, inventory, qty

I have a simple product,(one of many), that is linked to a configurable product.

I'm trying to get the salable quantity and attribute quantity to match.

The site is in a dev env, so I don't think any items would be in cart. But the database is from a live copy a few hours ago.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDa7f.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChPCi.png]

Toggling stock status, manage stock, changing data, re-indexing doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check `inventory_reservation`:

https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki/Salable-Quantity-Calculation-and-Mechanism-of-Reservations

If you don't want to use MSI (and stick to `CatalogInventory_*` from 2.2.7)- turn all `Inventory_*` modules off:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/install-extensions/inventory-management-installation.html#disable-inventory-management

EDIT:
According to @Umar comment and @Abude answer from question [How to disable the MSI in Magento 2.3?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273156/how-to-disable-the-msi-in-magento-2-3/282549#282549), you can disable all those  extensions by simply firing:

```
php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator
```

and then run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: This was it, I had a few orders that were in inventory reservations. Thanks

Comment: Awesome to hear :)

Comment: When I disable the module one by one with CLI its throw error of dependency and website going to the mashup.

Comment: @KrunalPandya, you can disable all modules once is through the commands mentioned here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/282549/58478. Magento will take care to prioritise disabling modules based on their dependencies.