# Product Page not found after Migration from Magento 1.9.3.8 to Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, product-page, 404, data-migration-tool

After successfully migrating from Magento 1.9.3.8 to Magento 2.3.4, I tried to check the category page, first, it doesn't show any products then I [disabled MSI modules](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/282549/84142) then it shows the products in the category. After that, I tried to click one of the product on the category page but it shows:

[image]

i already tried to truncate the following tables, then run reindex:

```
report_event
session
customer_visitor
catalog_url_rewrite_product_category
```

but nothing works, I already tried to disable the category URL then reindex, but nothing works.

Here are my view database tables:

[image]

Comment: Hey, can you try with test.loc/catalog/product/view/id/{{product-id}}, if this works than their is url rewrite issue?

Comment: @YashPatadia still Whoops, our bad