# Magento2: Not able to assign Source after enable the MSI module

Tags: magento2.3.3, stock, inventory, msi, multi-source-inventory

I have disabled the MSI inventory module (as explained in [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273156/how-to-disable-the-msi-in-magento-2-3) article) in my store. After facing some issues I have reverted back MSI related all modules, but after enabled all modules I am not able to assign Source in Manage stock.

[image]

Can Any one help me to fix this issue, because MSI is very complicated to debug the issue.